# Why does the "+" operator consider the number as string when added

Tags: javascript, operators

Why does the `+` operator consider the number as string when added

Ex :

```
'3' + 4 + 5;  // "345"
 3 + 4 + '5'; // "75"
```

Comment: String + whatever always yields string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` will only add two numbers if it has a number on the left hand side **and** a number on the right hand side.

```
'3' + 4 + 5;
```

First `'3' + 4` has a string on the left hand side. So it converts the right hand side to a string and concatenates them.

Second `'34' + 5` has a string on the left hand side. So it converts the right hand side to a string and concatenates them.

```
3 + 4 + '5';
```

First `3 + 4` has a number on both sides, so it adds them. Second `7 + '5'` has a string on the right hand side, so it converts the left hand side to a string and concatenates them.

Answer (score 4):

When using `+` with 2 numbers: Math.

When using `+` with a string: Concatenation.

```
3 + 4 = 7
7 + '5' = '75'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's simple rule in javascript :

```
string + number = string (operation work as a string)
'3' + 4 + 5; = 345
7 + '5' = 75
number + number = number (operation work as a number)
3 + 4 = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "why", you've already gotten answers, the way to fix it, in case you don't know or if it can help somebody else:

```
var x = parseInt('3') + 4 + 5;
```